# New dataframe with count of nrow of different dataframe

Tags: r

I have Four dataframe, like DF1,DF2,DF3 and DF4. I have calculated the NROW of all these four dataframe, now i want to create a new dataframe as shown below:

```
A<-NROW(DF1)
[1] 100
B<-NROW(DF2)
[2] 80
C<- NROW(Z)
[3] 30
C<-NROW(DF3)
[4] 50
D<-NROW(DF4)
[5] 25
```

Desired Output in New Dataframe:

```
DF    Count                   Count2            %
A     100                     0                 0%
B     80                      20(A-B)           20%
Z     15(Count2-Nrow(Z)       15(count"Z")      75% (count2"Z")/(Count2"B")
C     50                      30(B-C)           37.5%
D     25                      25(C-D)           50%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way perhaps, but here you go:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 100))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 80))
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 50))
df4 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 25))

df <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

count <- c(nrow(df1), nrow(df2), nrow(df3), nrow(df4))

count2 <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 4)

for(i in 1:4) {
  if(i == 1) {
    count2[i] <- 0
  } else {
    count2[i] <- count[i-1] - count[i]
  }
}

percentage <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 4)

for(i in 1:4) {
  if(i == 1) {
    percentage[i] <- 0
  } else {
    percentage[i] <- ((count[i-1] - count[i])/count[i-1]) * 100
  }
}

final_df <- data.frame(df, count, count2, percentage, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df5 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 15))
newrow <- c('Z', nrow(df5), nrow(df5), (nrow(df5)/count2[2] * 100))
final_df = rbind(final_df[1:2,], newrow, final_df[-(1:2),])
```

Result:

```
  df count count2 percentage
  A   100      0          0
  B    80     20         20
  Z    15     15         75
  C    50     30       37.5
  D    25     25         50
```

Comment: I want to add a new row betwenn B and C (let say it Z) and for that my count2 formula would be same but for C count2 as well as percentage formula would be (B-C) instead of (Z-C).

Comment: You can add another if condition in the second for loop, where you can input the formula there. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: can you please explain me i am not getting the desired output: I want to add a new row betwenn B and C (let say it Z) and for that my count2 formula would be (Count2(B)-Z) instead of (Z-C) and for percentage Count2(Z)/Count2(B).

And Now for C count2 as well as percentage formula would be (B-C) instead of (Z-C).

Comment: can you please help me out here.

Comment: Please edit your question and then add with expected output, I am still finding it hard to comprehend.

Comment: @trillster, edited the question as suggested by you. Please check.

Comment: edited the question as suggested by you, please check.

Comment: I'm still stuck... Please check.

Comment: Updated. And please Google these things. It is extremely easy to do what I have done. I have a very strong feeling you are putting no effort whatsoever.